# Outlook 2003 Default setting: Reply-to

Tags: active-directory, exchange, outlook-2003

In our company, our employees have a personal mailaccount and each department has a general purpose emailaccount (*department@example.com*), where all department members have access to. The clients access the Exchange server via Outlook 2003 and the proprietary Exchange-Protocol (and not via POP3 or IMAP).

I would like to set a default for the reply-to address of outoing mails, pointing to each departments general purpose mailaccount. This can be set on a per-mail basis via *New Mail -> Mailoptions... -> Reply-to*, but I am unable to set a default address for this field and also activate it by default.

Is this possible through Exchange or Active-Directory options? Everything I found so far handles POP3 or IMAP accounts, but nothing with Exchange configuration and -accounts, where these options do not exist.

*(Please Note: I do not want to set an Auto-Reply or Out-of-Office-Reply)*

Comment: So you want emails sent by userA to appear to come from departmentA@company.com? Likewise for userB, etc.?

Comment: yes and no - Would it be possible to set the "from:"-Field for a specific address to another account (basically what you just asked)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have typically used mail enabled public folders for this type of mailbox sharing arrangement.  I found it much easier to set up and control.  Also makes hte auditors happy to not have shared AD accounts.

If you are referrring to "reply from" when an email is replied to, then the primary smtp address is the "reply from". You can also give permissions to send as, then use the "from" select in Outlook to change who the email is from if other than default is desire.

Comment: That does not solve my problem - I can set so many defaults in exchange, but can't set a simple reply-to address?

Comment: If you are referrring to "reply from" when an email is replied to, then the primary smtp address is the "reply from".  You can also give permissions to send as, then use the "from" select in Outlook to change who the email is from if other than default is desired.